# Synonymize [qi4j] -> [apache-zest]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

I've seen a user posting a few edits with a tag addition:

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/14017359

Stating the reason behind it as:

> Added apache-zest tag, qi4j moved to the ASF and changed it's name to
>   Apache Zest

Rather than retagging them all, since they are the same product, should we make [qi4j](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/qi4j) and [apache-zest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache-zest) synonyms?

Should we be allowing these edits to go through if we don't make them a synonym?

Comment: Notifying the offender: @eskatos , your tag replacements are wrong. Either replace [tag:qi4i] with [tag:apache-zest] rather than an unrelated tag, or better yet, vote for the synonym here.